# Inserting elements in specific order in an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `X`. I want to insert elements of `X` at specific positions according to the list `T2` and for all other positions `0.0`and create a new `X`. For example, `4.17551036e+02` should be at `X[0]`, `3.53856161e+02` at `X[3]`, `2.82754301e+02` at `X[5]` and so on. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
X = np.array([4.17551036e+02, 3.53856161e+02, 2.82754301e+02, 1.34119055e+02,
       6.34573886e+01, 2.08344718e+02, 1.00000000e-24])

C1=0.0
T2=[0, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11]

for i in T2:
    X = np.insert(X, i, C1, axis=None)

print("X =", [X])
```

The current output is

```
X = [array([0.00000000e+00, 4.17551036e+02, 3.53856161e+02, 0.00000000e+00,
       2.82754301e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 1.34119055e+02, 6.34573886e+01,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       2.08344718e+02, 1.00000000e-24])]
```

The expected output is

```
X = [array([4.17551036e+02, 0.0, 0.0, 3.53856161e+02, 0.0,
       2.82754301e+02, 0.0, 0.0, 1.34119055e+02, 6.34573886e+01`,
       2.08344718e+02, 1.00000000e-24])]
```

Comment: First element of your T2 array is 0 (denoting the 0th index I believe), so inserting 0 at the first location is expected right?

Comment: in T2 you  have positions [0, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11], why in the expected output you have 0.0 in position 1, 2?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make sense, can you explain the steps more elaborately on how you are expecting the output based on T2

Comment: I have now edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is, filling the **rest of the values** apart from the ones in the T2 list with 0.0's. this might help you get started

```
X = np.array([4.17551036e+02, 3.53856161e+02, 2.82754301e+02, 
1.34119055e+02, 6.34573886e+01, 2.08344718e+02, 1.00000000e-24])

C1=0.0
T2=[0, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11]
index=0
for j in range(T2[-1]):

    if(j!=T2[index]):
        X = np.insert(X, j, C1, axis=None)
    else:
        index+=1
    
print("X =", [X])
```

Comment: Please check the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
from array import *
X=array('f',[4.17551036e+02, 3.53856161e+02, 2.82754301e+02, 
1.34119055e+02, 6.34573886e+01, 2.08344718e+02, 1.00000000e-24])

C1=0.0
T2=[0, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11]

Y=array('f',[])

i=0

for j in range (T2[-1]+1):
    if T2[i] == j:
        Y.append(X[i])
        i+=1
    else:
        Y.append(C1)
    

print(Y)
```

Comment: Output:

array('f', [417.551025390625, 0.0, 0.0, 353.8561706542969, 0.0, 282.7543029785156, 0.0, 0.0, 134.11904907226562, 63.45738983154297, 208.34471130371094, 1.0000000195414814e-24])

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use insert, especially not repeated ones.  Just assign the `X` values to the `T2` indices in a `zeros` array:

```
In [3]: X = np.array([4.17551036e+02, 3.53856161e+02, 2.82754301e+02, 1.34119055e+02,
   ...:        6.34573886e+01, 2.08344718e+02, 1.00000000e-24])

In [4]: T2=[0, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11]

In [5]: res = np.zeros(12)    
In [6]: res[T2] =X

In [7]: res
Out[7]: 
array([4.17551036e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 3.53856161e+02,
       0.00000000e+00, 2.82754301e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       1.34119055e+02, 6.34573886e+01, 2.08344718e+02, 1.00000000e-24])
```

To do it with one `insert`, `T2` has to be adjusted:

```
In [12]: np.insert(np.zeros(5), T2-np.arange(len(T2)), X)
Out[12]: 
array([4.17551036e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 3.53856161e+02,
       0.00000000e+00, 2.82754301e+02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       1.34119055e+02, 6.34573886e+01, 2.08344718e+02, 1.00000000e-24])
```